# Can I store application cache of HTML5 when packaging my hybrid app?

Tags: html, application-cache, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing an hybrid app.

It will bring contents from my server, and I will use application cache for performance and traffic cost issues.

Even though I use application cache, the users would have to download webpages whenever they open the pages first time.

I want to store the application cache before upload the app onto google play and apple app store.

Then, the app will only check manifest file if the page is not updated after packaging.

**Can I store the application cache in the hybrid app?** If then, where can I get the how-to documents, or how can I do that?

Thank you in advance!

p.s:I will package the webapp with phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

Better to answer late than never, I guess!

The answer is yes, it is possible. I've got two apps in the app store that are doing this. It works reasonable well, although it's a painful process (mainly because [appcache is a douche](http://alistapart.com/article/application-cache-is-a-douchebag))and we're using a customised version of Cordova in order to do it.

Here's a rough idea of how you can implement this:

- Have an empty local stub `index.html` that your Cordova `startPage` points at.
- Implement `webViewDidFinishLoad` in your webview. It will do two things - open the appcache page on start and inject your `cordova.ios.js` into the subsequent pages. Something like this:

  ```
  - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView {
      if(!_initialPageLoaded) {
          _initialPageLoaded = YES;
          NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://mywebsite.com/app/"];

          NSMutableURLRequest *req = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:ful];
          [self.webView loadRequest:req];

          return;
      }

      NSString* jsPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"www/cordova.ios" ofType:@"js"];
      NSString* c = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:jsPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

      [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:c];

      return [super webViewDidFinishLoad:webView];
  }
  ```
- Profit!

Note that the cordova.ios.js file is local to the application, so don't keep it on your webserver.